# Using RegEx to filter out decimals from float

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point, numbers, decimal

I have some `float` numbers with plenty of decimals. I've been trying to keep it neat by setting a maximum of two decimal digits.

Thus far I've used `toFixed(2)`. Just to keep things simple.

```
223.3284293.toFixed(2);
```

> "223.33"

I'm now in need of a more complex solution. I want the last *two* digits behind any trailing zeros.

**E.g** `1030.0002500082` would give me `1030.00025`.

In addition, I would want to exclude any trailing zero of the two digits.

**E.g** `400.002010082` would give me `400.002`.

Here are some more examples:

> `380.12939499` → `380.12`
>
> `0.00003909200049` → `0.000039`
>
> `0.0000004000004` → `0.0000004`
>
> `39094.03029900004` → `39094.03`
>
> `75.00000030000001` → `75.0000003`
>
> `5.000000000000000000000` → `5`

I figured using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) would be the best way of achieving this.

How would I specify that the two digits *after* the trailing zeros would be included, while still excluding any zero from those two digits?

Comment: What about `5.000000000000000000000`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir `5.000000000000000000000` would output `5`. Updated question with your example. Thanks.

Comment: This won't give you any rounding like you got with `223.3284293.toFixed(2);` is that going to be a problem ?

Comment: @sln No. I was only using `toFixed` because of its simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex replace:

```
str = str.replace(/^(\d*)(?:\.0*|(\.0*[1-9]{1,2}).*)$/, '$1');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJGfms/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^` - Start
- `(\d*)` match and capture number before dot in captured group #1
- `(?:` Start non-capture group

  - `\.0*` match dot followed by zero or more `0s`
  - `|` OR
  - `(\.0*[1-9]{1,2}).*` match dot followed by 0 or more `0s` followed 1 or 2 non-zeroes and captured it in group #2
- `)` End non-capture group
- `$` End

**Code Demo:**

```js
var arr = [
  '23.3284293',
  '1030.0002500082', 
  '400.002010082',
  '380.12939499', 
  '0.00003909200049', 
  '0.0000004000004', 
  '39094.03029900004', 
  '75.00000030000001', 
  '5.0000000'
];

arr = arr.map(str => str.replace(/^(\d*)(?:\.0*|(\.0*[1-9]{1,2}).*)$/, "$1$2"));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try following regex:

```
\d+(\.(0+|)[1-9][1-9]?|)
```

```js
let numbers = [
  '380.12939499', 
  '0.00003909200049', 
  '0.0000004000004', 
  '39094.03029900004', 
  '75.00000030000001', 
  '5.0000000'
];

let res = numbers.map(v => v.match(/\d+(\.(0+|)[1-9][1-9]?|)/)[0]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^(\d+(?:\.0*[1-9]{1,2})?).*$`; capture all integer parts and decimals (*the decimal part is optional so if the pattern doesn't match only take the integer part*) with up to two non zero digits following optional zeros:

```js
var examples = ['380.12939499', '0.00003909200049', '0.0000004000004', '39094.03029900004', '75.00000030000001', '5.000000000000000000000'];

console.log(
  examples.map(x => x.replace(/^(\d+(?:\.0*[1-9]{1,2})?).*$/, "$1"))
);
```